# Writing opengl es2 buffers to a file in java

Tags: java, opengl-es, 3d

I am using 3d models in obj/ply format in an opengl es2 engine which i have build. I am finding that the model loading takes a lot of time and resources. The model loading and engine are implemented in java. I heard that in C we can write the GLES buffers exactly as they are into a file and thus avoid the conversion. Is that possible with java?? Anybody know how it is done?